# Making a drawing app inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a drawing app inside a **bootstrap modal**.

So far I have achieved this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hj898aqb/)

Here's my code

```
var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvasDiv');
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute('width', 570);
canvas.setAttribute('height', 300);
canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
if(typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
    canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
}
context = canvas.getContext("2d");

$('#canvas').mousedown(function(e){
  var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

  paint = true;
  addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
  redraw();
});

$('#canvas').mousemove(function(e){
  if(paint){
    addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
    redraw();
  }
});

$('#canvas').mouseup(function(e){
  paint = false;
});

$('#canvas').mouseleave(function(e){
  paint = false;
});

var clickX = new Array();
var clickY = new Array();
var clickDrag = new Array();
var paint;

function addClick(x, y, dragging)
{
  clickX.push(x);
  clickY.push(y);
  clickDrag.push(dragging);
}

function redraw(){
  context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas

  context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
  context.lineJoin = "round";
  context.lineWidth = 5;

  for(var i=0; i < clickX.length; i++) {
    context.beginPath();
    if(clickDrag[i] && i){
      context.moveTo(clickX[i-1], clickY[i-1]);
     }else{
       context.moveTo(clickX[i]-1, clickY[i]);
     }
     context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
     context.closePath();
     context.stroke();
  }
}
```

But when the mouse is clicked, the drawing is being made way off from where the mouse pointer is. Check the fiddle to get an understanding of what I mean.

Also I would like to know how to make the **canvas** take the **height** and **width** of the **modal** and **not** pass in **static width** and **height** like this `canvas.setAttribute('width', 570);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.offsetleft is relative to parent element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft , so you need `$.offset`

2.height and width is according to parent after it shows

result see https://jsfiddle.net/hj898aqb/1/

Comment: Thanks for this. Works now